# TypeError: arr.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm working with reactjs and cannot seem to prevent this error when trying to display data from server.
my axios file:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {BASE_URL} from "../config";

export const readLectures = () => {
    return axios
        .get(`${BASE_URL}/api/lectures/all`)
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })

};
```

So, function readLectures return the array of lections. How should i write the function updateLecture corectle to wotk it good. How should i pass the data from server to setLection()? Please, help me. Thanks a lot.

```
import { readLectures } from '../../../api/lectures';
const StudentsViewing = (props) => {
  const [lection, setLection] = useState([]);

  const updateLecture = () => {
    readLectures(setLection({lection}))
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    updateLecture()
  }, [])

  const renderLectures = (arr) => {
    return arr.map((item, index) => {

      return (
        <CardItem item={item} />
      )
    })

  }

  const lectionCard = renderLectures(lection);

  const settings = {
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 900,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 4
  };

  return (
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {lectionCard}
      </Slider>
  )
}

export default StudentsViewing;
```

Comment: "readLectures return the array of lections" - from what i can see, it returns a promise. However, that return is never used anyways. This `readLectures(setLection({lection}))` looks like more than one problem got into a single line of code.

Comment: I tried to handle data with then:
**
 const updateLecture = () => {
    readLectures()
    .then((lection) => {
      setLection(lection)
    })} 
**
But it doesn't work and the error is: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: @Nastya Khudnytska It's because you are using the `useEffect` hook to call the `updateLecture` function, which in turn will update the Component because of the `state hook` `setLection`. Thus causing a cycle. Do you really need the `useEffect` to call the `updateLectures`?

Comment: @MD.TabishMahfuz yes, i need useEffect (as it work like ComponentDidMount in classes). I need to resresh data all time.

Comment: Then you will need a break condition to somehow stop calling the updateLectures method when it is not needed.

Comment: @MD.Tabish Mahfuz okey, if i don't need the `useEffect`, how i can organise the code to pull out data from the server and drawn it in my page in functional component? And also to refresh data as i did this in `ComponentDidMount` later. Could you help me if you know this?

Comment: I misread your code. You are already placing a blank array as the second parameter. This should stop `useEffect` from calling the updateLectures mehod after every state update. Oter than that, it reall shouldn't be going into that loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `readLectures` function returns a promise, so you can get the expected `array` inside the `then` callback. See below:

```
const updateLecture = () => {
    readLectures().then(lection => setLection(lection))
}
```

Or using the `async/await` syntax:

```
const updateLecture = async () => {
    setLocation(await readLectures())
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but the error "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop." appeared( I don't khow how to fix this.

Comment: @Nastya Khudnytska It's because you are using the `useEffect` hook to call the `updateLecture` function, which in turn will update the Component because of the state hook `setLection`. Thus causing a cycle. Do you really need the `useEffect` to call the `updateLectures`?